# How to evaluate the following limit ??

Tags: calculus

What is  limit
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}-x}{x^2\ln x}$$
You may use Taylor  expansion.
I don't know how to simplify the denominator....should we use Taylor expansion again for the denominator??

Comment: The expression isn't clear. Try to use LaTeX and/or parentheses. For example, that last $\,\ln x\,$, is multiplying the whole preceeding expression or only the $\;x^2\;$ in the denominator? In the left part you also don't have the same number of left and right parentheses...

Comment: Is this the expression you want to write?

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2), \quad x \to 0$$
and
$$e^{} = 1+y+o(y), \quad y \to 0$$
we have
$$\frac{(1+x)^\frac{\ln x}{x} - x}{x^2 \ln x} = \frac{e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}\ln(1+x)} - e^{\ln x}}{x^2 \ln x} = \frac{e^{\ln x}}{x^2 \ln x} [e^{\ln x (\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)-1)} - 1] = \frac{1}{x \ln x} [e^{\ln x(-\frac{x}{2} + o(x))} - 1] = \frac{1}{x \ln x} [-\frac{x \ln x}{2} + o(x \ln x)] \to -\frac{1}{2}, \quad x \to 0.$$